# rails + devise_token_auth gem - uid is same as email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise_token_auth gem for authentication. After successful signup, the use record created with the uid which is same as the user email. I just want to confirm whether this is the behaviour? or we should customize it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is the behavior of devise_token_auth.

https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/29#issuecomment-56090454

Comment: Oh yes. Thank you jhack for your quick response.